# Cannot open VCXSrv

Tags: windows-10, xorg, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-windows, vcxsrv

I am using Windows 10 Home on a Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop. I know the product is not tested for Windows 10 upgrade, but this question still applies.
When I open VCXSrv, it shows:

Cannot move old log file "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\VCXSrv.0.log" to "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\VCXSrv.0.log.old"

It appears that the program(running as User) have the right permissions.

I looked on Google search for an answer with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you still have an instance of VCXSrv running in Windows. This is why the log file cannot be moved. Check your hidden icons in the notification area of the Taskbar. You can also check in the Task Manager.

In short, either close the current display server or leave it be.